# Bitmapscaling mode does not make any difference

Tags: wpf, performance, rendering

I've tested the [BitmapScalingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode.aspx) but could not see any better result with maximum quality (Fant, Fantastic) to HighQuality. Now I see the values behind are the same. this is an bug of Microsofts Framework?

```
// Set the bitmap scaling mode for the image to render faster.
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(MyImage, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fant` and `HighQuality` are synonyms, as indicated in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode.aspx)...

> The LowQuality mode is the same as the Linear mode.
>   ...
>   The HighQuality mode is the same as the Fant mode.

So no, it's not a bug. It works as designed.